# When does the Lloyd polynomial have only integral roots?

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, diophantine-equations, coding-theory

For a $t$-error correcting code of length $n$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, the Lloyd polynomial is given by
$$
L_t(n,x):=\sum_{j=0}^t(-1)^j\binom{x-1}{j}\binom{n-x}{t-j}(q-1)^{t-j}.
$$
A well-known theorem by Lloyd and Lenstra is, that if the code is perfect, then
$L_t(n,x)$ has $t$ distinct integral zeros among $1,2,\ldots ,n$. The converse is not true in general. For example, with $q=2$, $t=2$ we have $L_2(n,x)=2x^2+2(n+1)x+\frac{n^2+n+2}{2}$.
This has integral roots if and only if $n=\ell^2+1$ for some integer $\ell$.

**Question:** What necessary, or sufficient conditions are known for the Lloyd polynomial to have only integral roots ? What else is known on integer roots for the Lloyd polynomial ?